# BASH : Concatenate directory and generated filename

Tags: php, linux, bash, cron, cron-task

I have a command in a CRONTAB like `php artisan mycommand:test` .

I want to write the output of my command into a daily generated filename like */var/log/cron/command-logs-2022-09-01.log*.

I did something like :

```
php artisan mycommand:test >> `date +"%Y-%m-%d"`\ `date +"H:%M:%S"`.log
```

And It worked perfectly. (filename like *2022-09-01 08:34:03.log*)

But when I add a directory before the filename it gives me **No such file or directory**

```
php artisan mycommand:test >> '/var/log/cron/'`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`\ `date +"H:%M:%S"`.log
```

```
bash: '/var/log/cron/'`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`\ `date +"H:%M:%S"`.log: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I find two points confusing: (1) The error message tells us, that bash did not evaluate the backquotes.  While backquotes of course are considered obsolete of course, they still should work. (2) Even without the proper evaluation of the backquoted part, the redirection should see a valid (though funny) filename, and the error message would mean that you don't have a directory `/var/log/cron`. For debugging, I would tackle the two problems separately: First store your complete path into a variable and check, whether the content makes sense, and then test for the existence of the directory.

Comment: Aside from this, you can make the whole expression simpler by doing a `>>"$(date "+/var/log/cron/%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo "php artisan mycommand:test >> '/var/log/cron/'`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`\ `date +"H:%M:%S"`.log"
php artisan mycommand:test >> '/var/log/cron/'2022-09-01\ H:44:03.log
```

Hence modify this to:

```
$ echo "php artisan mycommand:test >> /var/log/cron/'`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`_`date "+H:%M:%S"`.log"
php artisan mycommand:test >> /var/log/cron/'2022-09-01_H:44:40.log
```

Use:

```
$ php artisan mycommand:test >> /var/log/cron/`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`_`date "+H:%M:%S"`.log
```

OR:

```
$ php artisan mycommand:test >> /var/log/cron/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")_$(date "+H:%M:%S").log
```

Sample output:

```
$ echo "php artisan mycommand:test >> /var/log/cron/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")_$(date "+H:%M:%S").log"
php artisan mycommand:test >> /var/log/cron/2022-09-01_H:47:08.log
```

if Not having /var/log/cron/ directory

```
php artisan mycommand:test >> /var/log/cron_$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S.log")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, 
I tried both solutions but none worked.

It always shows me 
```
bash: /var/log/cron/`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`_`date "+H:%M:%S"`.log: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the error output : 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aA0YZcZ0ilq0RbKzLbOS43-9jbGQwCRn/view

Comment: Before executing that command, let us know the output of: 1) /var/log/cron/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")_$(date "+H:%M:%S").log 2) ls -ld /var/log/cron/

Comment: A side note: you don't need to invoke `date` twice. You can just say `date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S"`.

Comment: I am not having your OS here. Hence I tested that using windows cygwin (bash.exe).

Comment: if you are not having /var/log/cron/ directory try: ```php artisan mycommand:test >> /var/log/cron_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")_$(date "+H:%M:%S").log```

Comment: $ echo "php artisan mycommand:test >> /var/log/cron_$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S.log")"
php artisan mycommand:test >> /var/log/cron_2022_09_01_12_03_14.log

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan mycommand:test >> /var/log/cron/`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`_`date "+H:%M:%S"`.log
```

Worked as fine.
The problem is that I forget to create the **/var/log/cron** directory.